# Selenium Assert Equals to Value1 or Value2

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, testng

I want to test in Selenium (Java, Testng)
If my actual value is equal to one of the two values because my value can be Value1 or Value2 and both values will be correct.

If I want to assert only one equality I use this construction:

```
String expectedPopUpV1 = "Value1";
String expectedPopUpV2 = "Value2";
String actualPopUp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(Value)).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(actualPopUp,expectedPopUp);
```

but what should I do if I want to make something like

```
Assert.assertEquals(actualPopUp,expectedPopUp1||expectedPopUp1);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `assertTrue(boolean condition, String message)` for this and give the details in the message

```
boolean isEqual = actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUpV1) || actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUpV2);
Assert.assertTrue(isEqual, "The text " + actualPopUp + " is not " + expectedPopUpV1 + " or " + expectedPopUpV2);
```

Answer (score 2):

below option should also work using ternary operator:

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedPopUpV1.equalsIgnoreCase(actualPopUp )?expectedPopUpV1:expectedPopUpV2 , actualPopUp );
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any such method available. The two closest options I can think of:

```
if(!actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUp1) || !actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUp2) {
    Assert.fail("insert failure messsage here"); 
}
```

or

```
if(actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUp1) || actualPopUp.equals(expectedPopUp2) {
    Assert.assertTrue("insert message");
}
```

The other option would be to really extend the Assert capability by constructing your own with a Builder pattern to be in the tune of:

```
AssertBuilder.with(actualPopUp).equals(expectedPopUp1).or(expectedPopUp2);
```

But that may be too complicated for a simple use case.